# Azure DevOps pipeline variable group cannot list Key Vault

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have Azure DevOps pipeline variable group, which cannot list Key Vault. However pipeline can set secrets. What could be wrong?

NOT FINDING KEY VAULT AT ALL:

```
- Create Variable Group in Library of Azure DevOps
- Select Service Principal as Subscription
- No Key vault instance is listed in drop down
```

KEY VAULT ACCESS POLICY

```
- Application: Service Principal
- Key Permission: List
- Secret Permission: Get, List, Set
```

WORKING CODE IN PIPELINE:

```
$ConnectionString = az storage account show-connection-string -g $(resource-group) -n sa$(project- 
name)$(environment) -o "tsv"
$CurrentConnectionString = az keyvault secret show --name StorageAccountConnectionString --vault-name 
$(key-vault-name) --query value -o "tsv"
          if (!($ConnectionString -eq $CurrentConnectionString)) {
            az keyvault secret set -n StorageAccountConnectionString --vault-name $(key-vault-name) --value $ConnectionString -o none
          }
          else {
            write-host("Secret already in key vault!")
          }
```

Comment: I shared some troubleshooting methods in the answer, you can refer to it.  If it doesn't work, you may check if there are any error message on the UI page and share the `service connection` connection method(auto / manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you have set the `Secret Permission: Get, List` for the Service Principal, it could have access to use the Azure Key Vault in Azure Devops.

Since you couldn't see the Key Vault name in the drop downlist, you could try to check the Azure Service connection.

If you are using `Service principal (manual)`to create service connection, you need to make sure that the Service Principal is under the correct `Azure Subscription`.

[image]

On the other hand, you could create a new Service Principal with the following Azure Powershell script.

```
az account set --subscription <Azure-SubscriptionId>

az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
```

Then you could set the Key vault permission for the new Service Principal and use it in Azure Devops Service connection.

You could also try to use the `Service principal (automatic)` Azure Devops Service connection and check if it could see the keyvault.

[image]

Comment: I have create test key vault to same resource group and I can see this key vault listed. I did not add any access policy to service principal.

Comment: Then I created test key vault to different resource group where my actual key vault is also located. I did not add any access policy to service principal. This one is get not listed. Is there something wrong with my users rights to resource group? All key vaults are located in same subs.

Comment: Hi @Kenny_I. Could you please help us determine the Azure Devops Service connection method (Automatic or manual)? If the method is Automatic, it can only display the azure keyvault of a single resource group.

Comment: On the other hand, you could try to check the role of the service principal in Azure Subscriptions -> Access control(IAM) -> Role assignment. You could grant the `Reader role` to the service principal . Based on my test, in this case, the service principal  could see all azure key vaults(manual service connection).  You could refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application

Comment: Service Principal needed contribution access to Key Vault instance